# Numeric sort on an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array :

```
[ [ 1, 'a' ], [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 1, 'f' ], [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ] ]
```

and I would like to have :

```
[ [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ], [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'a' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ]
```

How can I do that with javascript please ?

I tried `sort()`, I also tried with `sort(compare)` with :

```
function compare(x, y) {
  return x - y;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare the first element in the nested array since you want to sort based on that number.

```
function compare(x, y) {
  return y[0] - x[0];
}
```

```js
var data = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [2, 'b'],
  [1, 'd'],
  [9, 'e'],
  [1, 'f'],
  [11, 'g'],
  [9, 'h'],
  [3, 'i']
];

function compare(x, y) {
  return y[0] - x[0];
}

data.sort(compare);

console.log(data);
```

---

In case you want to sort based on second element(secondary sorting in case the first element is same) then use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method for comparing.

```
function compare(x, y) {
  return y[0] - x[0] || x[1].localeCompare(y[0]);
}
```

```js
var data = [
  [2, 'b'],
  [1, 'd'],
  [9, 'e'],
  [1, 'f'],
  [1, 'a'],
  [11, 'g'],
  [9, 'h'],
  [3, 'i']
];

function compare(x, y) {
  return (y[0] - x[0]) || x[1].localeCompare(y[1]);
}

data.sort(compare);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Second example, Your code shows `&&` that's incorrect, but your code snippet is using `||` that's correct.  Had me baffled for a while,  how come his code snippet is working. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with [`Array Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) like this:

```
function compare([a], [b]) {
  return b - a;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let a = [ [ 1, 'a' ], [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 1, 'f' ], [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ] ];

a.sort(compare);

function compare([a], [b]) {
  return b - a;
}

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

In case first elements match, you can sort based on 2nd element as well:

```
function compare([a, c], [b, d]) {
  return (b - a) || c.localeCompare(d)
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let a = [ [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 1, 'f' ], [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ], [ 1, 'a' ] ];

a.sort(compare);

function compare([a, c], [b, d]) {
  return (b - a) || c.localeCompare(d);
}

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: `c > d`  I would avoid such sorting.  It might work here but sorting it's important that all three states can be captured.  `<` `=` & `>` doing just the two will work most of the time, but can fail.

Comment: @Keith What do you suggest instead of `>`?

Comment: Use the `-`  This will give you  all 3 states.

Comment: @Keith I've already tried with `-` but `-` doesn't seems to work with `string` data type. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zhc8pmo/)

Comment: Yes, for string `localeCompare` is better -> `(b - a) || c.localeCompare(d);`

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your input. I've got it and update as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the elements based on their first element, which is the number.

```js
var a = [ [ 1, 'a' ], [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 1, 'f' ], [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ] ];

a = a.sort((a,b) => {
    return b[0] - a[0]
});

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` to **compare first element and if first element is same then compare the second element**.

```
arr.sort( (a,b) => (b[0] - a[0]) || (b[1] - a[1]) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [ [ 1, 'a' ], [ 2, 'b' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 9, 'e' ], [ 1, 'f' ], [ 11, 'g' ], [ 9, 'h' ], [ 3, 'i' ] ];

arr.sort( (a,b) => (b[0] - a[0]) || (b[1] - a[1]) );

console.log(arr);
```